# iOS Date conversion from string bug

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdate

I have the following code:

```
-(NSString*) convertDateToString:(NSString*)dateString
{    
    NSDateFormatter *inputFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [inputFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ"];
    NSLocale *posix = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"];
    [inputFormatter setLocale:posix];
    NSDate *date = [inputFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

    NSDateFormatter *outFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [outFormatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd"];
    NSString *rv = [outFormatter stringFromDate:date];
    return rv;
}
```

Which I use to change the format of a Date String, so I basically input:

**Input:** 2001-10-03T00:00:00.000Z

**Output:** 10/02 (WRONG!) should be: *10/3*

So, the problem is that instead of getting 10/3 (which would be the correct result) I am getting 1 less (10/2). I am looking at the snippet but can't figure out where the error is.

This is the actual exact case:

[image]

Comment: just tested, it is working as expected. Can u please paste input date which u r passing in above function,

Comment: Gagan_iOS it's the example I used in the exaplanation: '2001-10-03T00:00:00.000Z'

Comment: working as expected. Tested on Xcode 10.3 and works fine. plz Just recheck ur code.

Comment: @Gagan_iOS I've added the actual, still failing, not sure what is going on..

Comment: I agree that this looks like a duplicate of the linked question from Cy-4AH. Can you check? If so, we can close this and point over there. (Your not setting a timezone on the formatter.)

Comment: It was still 2nd October in 2001 in your's location when it was Midnight 3rd October in Greenwich. `NSDateFormatter` works correctly.

Comment: you are right @Cy-4AH  Write the answer if you want and I'll mark it as correct. The original string was first minute of that day UTC, and I am running this from NYC which is -4 GMT, hence.. one day less.